# PHP Script Stalls During Loops

Tags: php, loops

The script below seems to stall for no reason during the loops. There are 6700 results to loop through, but it stalls between 375-460 results processed. No errors given or logged.

```
    <?php

/* Example usage of the Amazon Product Advertising API */
include("amazon_api_class.php");


ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



// define variables
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    //echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxx",$dbhandle) 
    or die("Could not select database");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM input ORDER BY mpn");
if (!$result) { // add this check.
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
//clear results table before processing
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE results");

mysql_close($dbhandle);


//loop
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$mfg = $row['mfg'];
$mpn = $row['mpn'];

$keyword = $mfg." ".$mpn;


    $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();

try{


    $data = $obj->getItemByKeyword($keyword);




$asin = $data->Items->Item->ASIN;
$weight = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight;
$height = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Height;
$length = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Length;
$width = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Width;
$manufacturer = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Manufacturer;
$brand = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Brand;
$partnumber = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->MPN;
$title = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title;
$upc = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->UPC;
$ean = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->EAN;
$pricenew = $data->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice;
$priceused = $data->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestUsedPrice->FormattedPrice;
$description = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Feature;
$title = $data->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title;

    echo '  processing  '.$counter++;



//connection to the database
$dbhandle1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");


//select a database to work with
mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxx",$dbhandle1)
    or die("Could not select db");


//execute the SQL query and return records
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `results`(`mpn`, `mfg`, `brand`, `asin`, `ean`, `upc`, `description`, `low_price_new`, `low_price_used`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `net_weight`, `gross_weight`, `shipped_weight`, `title`) VALUES ("'.$partnumber.'","'.$manufacturer.'","'.$brand.'","'.$asin.'","'.$ean.'","'.$upc.'","'.$description.'","'.$pricenew.'","'.$priceused.'","'.$length.'","'.$width.'","'.$height.'","'.$weight.'","'.$weight.'","'.$weight.'","'.$title.'")');
mysql_error();


 mysql_close($dbhandle1);

 //unset variables
 unset($asin);
 unset($weight);
 unset($height);
 unset($length);
 unset($width);
 unset($manufacturer);
 unset($brand);
 unset($partnumber);
 unset($packagequantity);
 unset($title);
 unset($upc);
 unset($data);
 unset($keyword);

 //flush
 flush();


 //force garbage collection
 gc_enable();
 gc_collect_cycles();






usleep(50000);
}
 catch(Exception $e)

{
//echo $e->getMessage();  
}
    //print_r($result);
}
echo "<br><h3>Job Completed</h3><br><br><h1><a href='csv_amz.php'>Download  Results As CSV File</a></h1><br><br><h1><a href='index.php'>Upload New File</a></h1>";
?>
```

My primary concern is to get this script to run through the entire list. When testing with 50-100 results, works without any problem.
As a secondary question, within the loop I have an echo with a counter. I would like to get that to display on screen in real time, instead of all at once when script finishes.

Comment: It used to be (back in the day) that PHP had a setting for execution time, and any script that went over that was instantly killed off. I'm unsure if this is still the case, but may be worth a check? Also: mysql_* methods should be replaced with mysqli_* - You'll get a lot of responses to that effect.

Comment: and big up for commenting `flush()` with //flush

Comment: I'm guessing that there's probably a product title (or similar) containing an apostrophe coming in from the Amazon Product API which is breaking your (unsanitised) SQL query... but there are other issues here (including the aforementioned use of the deprecated *mysql_* extension) - I think you need to find a PHP tutorial that was written more recently than the Napoleonic Wars I'm afraid. Oh, and the counter can't be updated in "real time" through raw PHP - server-side script completes before it's read by the browser.

Comment: Depending on the setup of the server I've had mixed success combining `flush()` and `ob_flush()` to get real-time progress messages.

Comment: @LokiSinclair already mentioned the timeouts - if you are close to a 30-second or 60-second timer fairly consistently then this is a likely source of the problem. Recently I had a long-running process and so I kept track of the timer and when I was about 10 seconds away I would redirect back onto the same page with an argument telling me where to pick up the process. YMMV.